# Website displaying images I removed from directory

Tags: html, flask, bootstrap-4

Very new to this so sorry if this is dumb.

I'm trying to display images on a web page. The images show up fine, but when I update or make changes to the image, the older version persists. So, for example, I load an image, decide to swap it out for another one, remove the old image from my image folder, add the new one, but the old version of the image is what continues to show. I've found that if I rename the image I can get it to change, but I don't want to keep renaming my images "Icon4", "Icon7", etc. as that gets messy.

```
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="/static/img/cv_icon.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to browser cache. Try adding a random number to the image url.

I assume your page is in php:

```
<img src="/static/img/cv_icon.png?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it. So putting 2 and 2 together I'm assuming this means that when I update images on the page I'll need to change the name of the image or else all visitors will see the old image unless they clear their cache? Best practice would be to just add a random number with each update?

Comment: Best practice would be to use mozilla firefox as the web browser during development, it is quite development friendly and you wont face such problems.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right, what you're saying is that you change the content of the image(update the image) and when you check the website, it remains the same?

Well, what could be happening is that your browser might be saving it in cache memory so as long as it seems to be the same to the computer, it won't change anything. What you'll do is to delete your cache memory.